# Accessing the Index of Non-Contiguous Visible Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data table that filters a column, "Product", based on the user's autofilter selections. I also have "Product" defined as a dynamically named range, which we'll define as A2:A30 for this example. Afterward, I would like to further manipulate the visible cells. A snippet of my debugging code:

```
Dim xName As Range
Set xName = ThisWorkbook.Names("Product").RefersToRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Debug.Print xName.Count
Debug.Print xName(3)
```

xName.Count would always return the correct number of visible cells, but accessing the index of xName proves troublesome when dealing with non-contiguous hidden cells. For instance, if A2:A5 and A8:A11 are the hidden cells, xName(1) would return A6's value, but xName(3) would return A8's value instead of A12's value. This makes it near impossible for me to loop through just the visible cells.

Is there an index manipulation I can do to only work with visible cells? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For non-contiguous ranges you can loop using `For Each`.

E.g.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range

    'create a non-contiguous test range
    Set rng = Range("A3:D4,A7:D7,A10:D16")

    'loop over each row in the range
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        Debug.Print rw.Address()
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to recognize the visible cells in my xName range. However, I don't believe a "For Each" would work for me since other variables will need to reference the same index.

Comment: I might have to combine your method with a .Add to a collection in order for indexing to happen

Comment: If you really need to index by a numeric value then Yes, you could wrap this in a function which returns a collection or an array.  It's not clear what you're doing with the visible range, so difficult to suggest exactly what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want to do: iterate over the areas of the range because it has been split into many areas due to the hidden ranges.

```
Set xName =ThisWorkbook.Names("Product").RefersToRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For i = 1 to xName.Areas.Count
    For j = 1 to XName.Areas(i).Count
        Debug.Print i, j, XName.Areas(i).Cells(j)
     Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
Sub test()
    Dim xName As Range
    Set xName = ThisWorkbook.Names("Product").RefersToRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print xName.Count
    Debug.Print VisibleCell(xName, 3)
End Sub

Function VisibleCell(rng As Range, index As Long) As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Long
    i = 0
    r = 1
    Do
        Do While rng(r).EntireRow.RowHeight = 0 Or rng(r).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 0
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
        If i = index Then
            Set VisibleCell = rng(r)
            Exit Do
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Function
```